# How do I print a whole CSV file to a Text entry box in Tkinter?

Tags: python, csv, tkinter, python-3.4

I would like to know what ways there are to write a whole CSV file to a `Text` entry box. My file isn't huge so there is not an issue with data handling and processing.

Answer (score 1):

Just open the file, read it, and insert the data:

```
...
the_text_widget = tk.Text(...)
...
with open("the_file.csv", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
    the_text_widget.insert("1.0", data)
```